# Already Mobile Number Exists Validation Pattern html forms

Tags: html, forms, validation

Is there any pattern if already mobile number exists then the error message has to be shown in form validation.

Comment: Mobile number exists where? In your Database? local storage? Add more details

Comment: Mobile number exists in the database

Comment: if you want to do this without loading the page you should use ajax request for checking in the database then show the result as required.

Answer (score 0):

If existing mobile numbers are present in the database, then you should make an API request to your backend using Ajax to avoid page reload. You should send the mobile number as a parameter in the request.

On the backend side, you need to check in the database that if this number already exists or not and based on your finding you should return appropriate responses.

On frontend, you need to check the response returned from the API and make appropriate decisions based on it but all the validation through the database should be done on the backend/server side.